# RSpec (Rails): Generate factories once for test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am running into issues with RSpec and FactoryBot and some factories because different tests try to generate the same factories which is not possible due to uniqueness constraints - and also logically wrong.
I would like to somehow centrally create the factory objects, so that each test has access to them instead of having "before..." or "let..." blocks / directives in different test files.
How to achieve that?

Example problem:
I have these factories:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :office_tk, class: Shelf do
    name { 'Office tk' }
    association :user, factory: :me
  end
end
```

and

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :hobbit, class: Book do
    title { 'The Hobbit' }
    year { 1937 }
    rating { 5 }
    condition { 4 }
    synopsis {  "<p>#{Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(number: 30).join(' ')}</p>" }
    association :book_format, factory: :hardcover
    association :user, factory: :me
    genres { [ create(:fiction) ] }
    association :shelf, factory: :office_tk
  end
end
```

and

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :me, class: User do
    name { 'tkhobbes' }
    email { 'me@example.com' }
    password { 'password' }
    password_confirmation { 'password' }
    admin { true }
    activated { true }
    activated_at { Time.zone.now }
  end
end
```

When I try to run this test - it complains because it tries to create :me twice (which is not possible, as each user / email can only exist once - apart from the fact that :me should be the same object for both the book and the shelf).

```
RSpec.describe Shelf, type: :model do
  before(:all) do
    @book = create(:hobbit)
  end
  it 'shows the right shelf for a book' do
    expect(@book.shelf.name).to eq('Office tk')
  end
end
```

Comment: you should be cleaning the database (see Database Cleaner gem) after each test, then you will not run into the uniqueness constraint. You could also generate these models in a before(:suite) callback in your spec_helper.rb file. But if you're not cleaning the database after every test, you will inevitably run into other problems.

Comment: OK so I got that and I will look at doing this before(:suite) callback (wasn't aware this is possible). I do have database cleaner setup and I think I only have it for "before:suite" ... so will need to correct that too. However in above example - I guess both my shelf factory AND my book factory calls the factory ":me" - and hence tries to create that user twice...? How do setup these factories to reuse what is there?

Comment: you have to use a conditional create. `before(:all) do; unless (@book = Book.find_by(name: 'hobbit')); @book = create(:hobbit); end; end;` I probably didn't correctly understand your app in that example, but you can get the gist of conditional create in before(:all). But I would recommend cleaning the db after each test.